# fullcalendar different events cell background color

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

The below code is the one I have found from blogs to change event cell background color. But event render is changing cell color of all the events.

```
event Render : function (event, element) {
    var dataToFind = moment(event.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    $(" td [data-date='"+dataToFind+"']").addClass('activeDay');
}
```

My issue is I have two different events and I want to change cell background color for only one event and other event should be normal.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier if you change the event colour for different events rather than changing the cell color?

Comment: But my client's requirement is to change the cell color !!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the above by two ways

1. Use the `eventAfterAllRender` callback instead of `eventRender` and use the condition you need for example you want to add class to current day

   ```
   var dataToFind = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
   $(" td [data-date='"+dataToFind+"']").addClass('activeDay');
   ```
2. Use the `eventRender` callback, in the function write the below snippet.

if you want add '`activeDay`' class to today then

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {
   var today = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
   var dataToFind = moment(event.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD');

   if (today == dataToFind) {
      $(element).addClass('activeDay');
   }
}
```

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer, But the below own code helps me in my scenario,

```
if (event.title.match("^XXXX:")) {
                        var start = new Date(event.start);
                        var end = new Date(event.end);
                        var dateDiff = end.getDate() - start.getDate();
                        if (moment(event.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD') != moment(event.end).format('YYYY-MM-DD')) {
                            for (i = 0; i < dateDiff + 1; i++) {

                                $("td[data-date='" + moment(start).add('days', i).format('YYYY-MM-DD') + "']").addClass('activeDay')
                            }
                        }
                        else if (moment(event.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD') == moment(event.end).format('YYYY-MM-DD')) {
                            $("td[data-date='" + moment(event.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD') + "']").addClass('activeDay');
                        }
                    }
```